# Do OCAML lists support sort_uniq?

Tags: ocaml

I was looking at this documentation for the OCAML List module and I tried to use the sort_uniq function but I got an Unbound value error. Does anyone know why this happens or can suggest an alternative method to eliminate the duplicates from a list?

What works:

```
List.sort compare ls;;
```

What doesn't work:

```
List.sort_uniq compare ls;;
```

Comment: you need OCaml 4.02 or later.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using an old version of OCaml, `List.sort_uniq` is rather recent, iirc. Apparently it was not marked as new in the manual.

Comment: I ended up implementing it myself since it's not that big of a deal, but it's nice to know that I should update my OCaml version, thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's worth reporting a bug against this issue on OCaml bts (http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/my_view_page.php) if this is not already the case. Such version information is important if you want to provide code compatible with various OCaml versions.